# change border color of rectangle when it contains a point or the points in c++ using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I need help changing the color of a rectangle in a grid. So far, I have the rectangles and the grid (which are lines drawn separating the rectangles), and I want to change the color of a single rectangle when it contains any point or points.

[image]

my code looks like below:

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 254;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

void myDrawGrid(Mat &img, int Rows, int Cols, int R, int C)
{
    float Height = (img.rows - 1) / Rows;
    float Width = (img.cols - 1) / Cols;


    for (int i = 0; i <= Rows; ++i) {
        line(img, Point(0, i*Height), Point(img.cols, i*Height), Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= Cols; ++i) {
        line(img, Point(i*Width, 0), Point(i*Width, img.rows), Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
    }

    int pixel_Dist = 3;

    rectangle(img, Point(C*Width + pixel_Dist, R*Height + pixel_Dist), Point((C + 1)*Width - pixel_Dist, (R + 1)*Height - pixel_Dist), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    src = imread("E:/emptyhighway.jpg", 1);
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);


    int ROWS = 11, COLS = 11;
    for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < COLS; ++c) {
            myDrawGrid(src, ROWS, COLS, r, c);
        }
    }

    Mat threshold_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
    vector<Point2f>center(contours.size());
    vector<float>radius(contours.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
        minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i]);
    }

    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3);

    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(0, 0, 240);
        circle(src, center[i], 2, color, 2, 8, 0);
        circle(drawing, center[i], 2, color, 2, 8, 0);

        cout << "{id:" << i << ",x:" << center[i].x << ",y:" << center[i].y << "}," << flush;

    }

    cout << "\n \n" << flush;


    imwrite("FinalImg.jpg", src);
    namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Contours", drawing);
    char* source_window = "Source";
    namedWindow(source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(source_window, src);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);

}
```

Is there any method to achieve it?

Comment: You have std::vector of detected points and you know coordinates of all rectangles. Maybe you will simply process all rectangles with existence/absence at least one element of point from your point set inside a rectangle (one "for" operator inside the second "for" operator)?

Comment: You could use the openCV function `cv::pointPolygonTest`. I would iterate through all n points and all m rectangles and if the function returns true, you could change the color of rectangle m.

Comment: Hi, @Grillteller appreciate your idea. I've gone through your idea but when i use vector<Rect> it's not working. I have to make a rectangle using polylines and after that the function cv::pointPolygonTest works fine.